# How to move the position of a javascript based HTML element with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datetime

I wanted to move the date and time to some what down from the head.
I am not getting how to do that:

```css
 /* the CSS which I am using is */

    p {
        
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 15%;
    }
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

but it is not working.

Comment: you want to display date time at bottom of page?

Answer (score 0):

Made a fiddle by copying and pasting your code... Seems to work just fine for me.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

Putting that in the html field is all you need, but I can't say why it isn't working in your code. Check for tags you haven't closed, extra or missing ', ", /, etc...

https://jsfiddle.net/of8692m3/

Comment: Sorry, quick fork - https://jsfiddle.net/of8692m3/1/ - I DID say all you needed was the first bit in the HTML section. So here ya go, displays the date just fine.